# Insert values to an ArrayList like intervals java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, insert, range

I have a set of ranges that represent the values I have.
When a new range is added, the intervals between the ranges might be deleted.

Example:
I have ranges `[10, 50]`, `[70, 100]`, `[150, 200]`, where the data is kept in two lists:
`start_list` (10, 70, 150) & `end_list` (50, 100, 200).

Here are 4 different possible inputs I might get with the expected output:

1. `[20, 170]` result should be `[10, 200]` since all intervals have been added.
2. `[5, 170]`  result should be `[5,  200]` since all intervals have been added.
3. `[20, 220]` result should be `[10, 220]` since all intervals have been added.
4. `[1, 120]`  result should be `[1,  120]`, `[150, 200]` since some intervals have been added.

However, I cannot seem to get this method to work. Can anyone help me solve this problem? I can not make the conditions right..

Comment: Can you share the _code_, please?

Comment: Agreeing with @Mick Mnemonic. Please share code for us to help

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this using Guava.

```
RangeSet<Integer> r = TreeRangeSet.create();
r.add(Range.closed(10, 50));
r.add(Range.closed(70, 100));
r.add(Range.closed(150, 200));

// adds
r.add(Range.closed(20, 170));
//      r.add(Range.closed(5, 170));
//      r.add(Range.closed(20, 220));
//      r.add(Range.closed(1, 120));

System.out.println(r);
```